# How to find words repeated 5 times in a text file in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, conditional-statements, python-3.9

I was trying to code a word counter program which selecting word from a random text file. The condition is that words that repeat 5 or more times will be written on the screen. I tried many examples. I tried count() function with if condition like this:

> if fullText.count(word) > 5:...

but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

main = Tk()
main.title(".TXT File Word Counter")
main.resizable(height=FALSE, width=FALSE)
main.geometry('500x400')
main.configure(bg='#757575')

labelfont = ("Arial", 14, "bold")

result = dict()

def clear_text():
    textfield.delete(0, END)
    ShowCountedWords.delete(1.0, END)

def open_file():
    main.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

def count_word(file):
    fileOpen = open(str(file), 'r')
    fullText = fileOpen.readlines()
    fileOpen.close()
    for word in textfield.get().split(', '):
        for text in fullText:
            if word in result:
                result[word] = result[word] + text.count(word)
            else:
                result[word] = text.count(word)
    ShowCountedWords.delete(1.0, END)
    for key, value in result.items():
        ShowCountedWords.insert('1.0', '{0} : {1} \n'.format(key, value))

    result.clear()


heading = Label(main, text=".TXT File Word Counter")
heading.place(x=150, y=2)
heading.config(bg="#757575", font=labelfont, fg="#ffffff")

textfield = Entry()
textfield.place(x=3, y=30)
textfield.config(width=81, borderwidth=2)

btnSelectFile = Button(main, text="Select .txt File", command=lambda : open_file())
btnSelectFile.place(x=4, y=60)
btnSelectFile.config(width=20, bg="#66BB6A")

btnCount = Button(main, text="Count Words", command=lambda : count_word(main.filename))
btnCount.place(x=173, y=60)
btnCount.config(width=20, bg="#42A5F5")

btnClear = Button(main, text="Clear", command=lambda : clear_text())
btnClear.place(x=344, y=60)
btnClear.config(width=20, bg="#ef5350")

ShowCountedWords = Text(main, height=18, width=61)
ShowCountedWords.place(x=4, y=100)
ShowCountedWords.config(bg="#616161", fg="#ffffff")


main.mainloop()
```

What should I do? (tkinter is unimportant at this problem.)

Comment: you can go word by word and add every new word to a dictionary where the key is the word and the value is the number of times it appears, then run through the dictionary and print only keys which values are equal to 5

Comment: What @SH describes is a good strategy, and has a built-in class `collections.Counter` to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` module to find all words in a string, then use `collections.Counter()` to count occurrence of words.

Below is an example:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

# found all words
words = re.findall(r'[\w]+', data)
# count occurrence of words
result = Counter(words)
# show all words with occurrence >= 5
print([word for word, count in result.items() if count >= 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
fullText.replace(",","")
fullText.replace(".","")
for word in textfield.get().split(' '):
   #your code
```

if you split the string with ", " most words will get skipped

Answer (score 0):

In your loop "for text in fullText" you are iterating through a list of lines from the file you opened, not a list of words to add to a dictionary. Your logic is correct, iterate through the list, find a word, and if it already exists in the dictionary add a count to it and if not, make it a new instance with count = 1. However, you need to split each line from the list of lines into a sublist of words, and those are the words you want to be iterating through.